# Python3 Pandas replacing on rows based on inner condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, replace

With this simplified dataframe :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
d_price = [np.nan,'7,5',np.nan]
df = pd.DataFrame(d_price, columns = ['d_price'])

    d_price
0    NaN
1    7,5
2    NaN
```

How to replace ',' by '.' ONLY where necessary ? To have :

```
    d_price
0    NaN
1    7.5
2    NaN
```

I tried :

```
df.d_price.mask(df.d_price.str.constains(','), df.d_price.str.replace(',','.'), inplace=True)
```

But got this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "test-sftp.py", line 382, in proceect has no attribute \'constainsss_file\n    df.d_price.mask(df.d_price.str.constains(\',\'), df.d_price.str.replace(\',\',\'.\'), inplace=True)\nAttributeError: \'StringMethods\' object has no attribute \'constains\'\n'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the condition using [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and then only replace:

```
In [3453]: import numpy as np
In [3454]: df.d_price = np.where(df.d_price.str.contains(','), df.d_price.replace(',', '.', regex=True), df.d_price)

In [3455]: df
Out[3455]: 
  d_price
0     NaN
1     7.5
2     NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean:

```
df['d_price'].str.replace(',','.')
```

Output:

```
0    NaN
1    7.5
2    NaN
Name: d_price, dtype: object
```

And also, it's `.str.contains` not `.str.constains`.